# What does this Python if statement evaluate to?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and have to convert a program to Java. I'm stuck at this statement:

```
if not all(cId in historyCId[rOBE] for cId in cIds):
```

What is the statement in `if()` evaluating to? (An explanation in words is desired.)

`historyCId` is a `HashMap`; `cIds` is a `JSONArray`.

Comment: why do you tag this as Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for each json cId in jsonArray cIds:
 if ((even one)cId is not in arraylist of key historyCId[rOBE])
   return true
 else
  return false
```

Comment: Thanks, value of hashmap is an arraylist, i was not getting that

Comment: It can also be a dictionary, check its declaration.

Answer (score 4):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) show exactly what `all()` does:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

In other words, you could rewrite your statement as:

```
result = True
for cId in cIds:
    if not cId in historyCId[rOBE]:
        result = False
        break
if not result:
    # do something
```